# bootstrap modal does not load on second click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I am showing notifications on modal with ajax call, ajax and php code is fine, It shows notifications on modal only first time, on second click at anchor it does not load `"modal-dialogue"` div and `"modal-content"` but it loads `"modal fade modal-form in"` div. When I debug it I saw display none on both above div's I know I can handle them with javascript, but I think that's not the solution.

What I am missing there, please guide

```
<a class="flag-list" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#user-flag">
  <i class="icon-flag6"></i>' . esc_html__( 'Flag as inappropriate' ) .
</a>
<div class="modal fade modal-form" id="user-flag" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"> 
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span> 
        </button>
        <h3 class="modal-title" id="flagModalLabel">
          <?php echo esc_html__( 'Flag' ); ?>
        </h3>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form id="cs_flag_user">
          <input type="hidden" name="name_one">
          <input type="hidden" name="name_two">
          <textarea></textarea>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I see a form inside your modal, are you submitting the form or doing any action inside the modal when you opened it for the first time.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you may have a problem in server side, the code in your page, or any form submissions which changed may be the DOM, It will be easier to open the console and figure out exact problem.

A full demo for your code is running in [Codepen here](https://codepen.io/msolimans/pen/PJXJXE). I just replaced your `php` code with simple text, check it and leave your comment in case you need more help.

If you need to work with modal windows easily, I already wrote and open sourced modal windows wrapper plugin based on bootstrap4, you can find also [demos and how to use here](http://bscom.msoliman.me/modals/).

Answer (score 0):

Try avoiding data-toggle="modal" data-target="#user-flag"

and use jquery to display and hide modals.

If notifications are loaded via ajax, then display modal inside success of that ajax.